# How to filter the List in the List then return it?

Tags: kotlin

Is there a solution that filters the List in the List, then returns a List?

For Example:

```
[group : {name:"group1", 
  student :[student1:{age:10},student2:{age:11},student3:{age:12}]},
group : {name:"group2", 
  student :[student1:{age:11},student2:{age:12},student3:{age:14}]},
]
```

I wanna filter the student's age greater than 10 and less than 13.

The result should be like this:

```
[group : {name:"group1", 
  student :[student2:{age:11},student3:{age:12}]},
group : {name:"group2", 
  student :[student1:{age:11},student2:{age:12}]}
]
```

Comment: What types are `group` and `student`s? Are they classes defined by you?

Comment: yes, there are Students in the Group. and there are also many Groups

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can map the group list to itself while filtering the students. If your Group is a data class you can do the following:

```
val filtered = original.map { group ->
    val students = group.student.filter { it.age in 11..12 }
    group.copy(student = students)
}
```

The inner filter will remove the unneeded students and the copy will duplicate your original group, but changes the student list to the filtered one.

Comment: I like the copy approach. I always tend to forget the `data class` goodness.